# Is it possible to make a script to watch and download videos from youtube playlists?

Tags: download, youtube

I listen to a lot of music on youtube and create my own playlists, but I keep finding that videos are often quickly deleted or made private on the channel's account, so I end up with a playlist full of videos that I can't access.

I was wondering if it was possible to write a script to watch a specific playlist of mine, and download any videos that are added to it (either instantly or periodically) so I can have the videos in some kind of music/video format to play on my own machine?

Comment: Maybe I miss understood but what good is a playlist if the video gets deleted or made private?

Comment: That's exactly why I want to be able to automatically download songs, so if they are deleted or made private, I haven't lost them

Comment: Joe, can you please edit your post ([click here to edit](http://superuser.com/posts/799886/edit)) and explain that as the question isn't totally clear. It will help others to understand and hopefully get you an answer :)

Comment: Have your heard of [youtube-dl](http://youtube-dl.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer:

You can use [ByTubeD](http://msram.github.io/bytubed/dev-versions/1.1.2a2.xpi) plugin with Mozilla Firefox and IDM.

Long Answer:

- Install above mentioned addon in your Firefox.
- Go to the Youtube playlist and right-click on its title.
- Select ByTubeD option.
- Your videos will take a while to get parsed into a list.
- Select the videos you want to download.
- Select resolution and video format.
- Select destination where the html page with parsed links will get saved.
- Open the saved html page(if not opened already) and right click on any link.
- Select 'Download All Links With IDM'.
- Voila! Now all you need to do is to go to your IDM and open its Scheduler, then go to second tab and remove all the old files which are on the top of your IDM's queue.

Comment: It's nice that you found a discontinued plugin, but your continuing to post the same answer is akin to spamming

Comment: The link goes directly to the plugin itself, so it's very likely to be spam (but I cannot confirm that it is indeed).